@import making the rest of my css stylesheet not work
When I put in the @import tags above everything else in the style sheet as seen below, it makes the rest of the style sheet stop working, but if I remove the @imports, everything works. What can I do to fix it?
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&#39;);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,700&#39;);
body {
  background-image:url(images/stripbg.jpg);
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

I deleted the @imports and the style sheet worked, but if I add them back, nothing works, including the fonts.

Your url value is not valid as it contains a html entity #39; this will break subsequent style rules. Replace this entity with a singele quote and everything should work fine @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
